# Generating ListBox Items from Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a ListBox using VBA in excel. Currently when running the form I am unable to edit the list box and nothing will generate.

I am trying to generate the values from a column in a table

**ListBox Name:** client_code_lb
**worksheet name:** client_info
**table name:** client_info

```
Sub client_code_lb_LoadTable()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim cell As Range

'Store Table Object to a variable
 Set tbl = client_info.ListObjects("client_info")

'Load List Box
 For Each cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells
    client_code_lb.AddItem cell.Value
 Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the ListBox an ActiveX form control?

Comment: what kind of listbox?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a listbox on a form

> Currently when running the form

```
Sub client_code_lb_LoadTable()

dim myArr as Variant

' fill array from table's column
myArr= client_info.ListObjects("client_info").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).value

' fill listbox from array
client_code_lb.List=myArr

End Sub
```

Note: you should reconsider the use of snake case naming. [Read This.](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/clean-vba-code-pt-1-bad-habits/)